# Eval in safari throws error on proper es6 code

Tags: javascript, safari, ecmascript-6, eval

So I have this completely legit piece of code that uses es6 default parameter:

```
const foo = 5;
function test(bar = foo) { return bar };
test();
```

It works properly when executed in Safari's console.

However the same piece of code, when used inside an eval function, like so:

```
eval('const foo = 5; function test(bar = foo) { return bar }; test();');
```

throws the following error:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: foo

I stumbled upon this when working with webpack sourcemaps (`eval-source-map`) that generate code wrapped in eval like this, and it breaks the generated bundle.

I was wondering why this inconsistency?

Tested in Safari v 10.1.2

Comment: Seems to work in Safari 11 so it might be just a bug.

Comment: Looks like a bug related to the `const`/`let` keywords. Appears to work with `var` in Safari 10.

Comment: @PatrickKunka Yes it does work with var, seems like maybe issue with block scoped variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a bug related to usage of block-scoped `const` / `let`, and the fact that the code is being evaluated in the global scope.

I've found two work arounds:

1: use `var`:

```
eval('var foo = 5; function test(bar = foo) { return bar }; test();');
```

2: Use `const`, but execute within a closure. For example, the same code inside a IIFE appears to work:

```
eval('(function(){const foo = 5; function test(bar = foo) { return bar }; return test();})()');
```